# Does canceling a $timeout in the following 'then' function work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, angular-timer

I do this kind of all the time and I'm not too sure it works.  If it does, How can I check?  If it doesn't whats a better method of canceling a timeout after it's completed?

```
var delay = $timeout(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < allHighlightedEls.length; i += 1) {
       //... some transformations
      }
    }, 1000)
      .then(function() {
        $timeout.cancel(delay);
      });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After it is completed, it is completed. There is nothing left to cancel.

Calling `cancel` on it does nothing.

Comment: Interesting... I read all these articles saying cancel your timeouts... I guess I have no idea what I'm doing.